# Преобразование вещественного числа в двоичное (10010) и наоборот

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как можно сделать перевод вещественного десятичного числа в двоичное (FloatToBin -> BinToFloat) на C#.
Спасибо!

**Добавлено.**

```
public static string IntToBin(long number, bool eraseLeftOffBits = true)
{
    var result = string.Empty;

    for (var i = 0; i < sizeof (long)*8; i++)
        result = ((number & ((long) 1 << i)) != 0 ? '1' : '0') + result;

    return eraseLeftOffBits ? result.TrimStart(new[] {'0'}) : result;
}

public static long BinToInt(string binaryNumber)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(binaryNumber))
      return 0;

   long result = 0;
   const byte maxCellIndex = sizeof (long)*8;
   var maxPosition = (binaryNumber.Length > maxCellIndex ? maxCellIndex : binaryNumber.Length);
   var binaryNum = binaryNumber.Substring(binaryNumber.Length - maxPosition, maxPosition);
   for (var i = 0; i < maxPosition; i++)
       if (binaryNum[maxPosition - i - 1] == '1')
           result |= ((long) 1 << i);

   return result;
}
```

Мне надо тоже самое только для вещественных чесел...

Answer (score 1):

Взято тут: [converting from decimal to binary and back](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial137_Converting-from-decimal-to-binary-and-back.html).

В бинарный

```
private string ToBinary(Int64 Decimal)
{
    Int64 BinaryHolder;
    char[] BinaryArray;
    string BinaryResult = "";

    while (Decimal > 0)
    {
        BinaryHolder = Decimal % 2;
        BinaryResult += BinaryHolder;
        Decimal = Decimal / 2;
    }

    BinaryArray = BinaryResult.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(BinaryArray);
    BinaryResult = new string(BinaryArray);
    return BinaryResult;
}
```

Обратно

```
Convert.ToInt64("010101010101", 2).ToString();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но это не вещественное число... мне нужно с float, double например...

Comment: стоп, а какой нужен формат битового значения? запись вещественного числа (насколько помню) в двоичном формате примерно так 
     1001010101Е101010111
то есть после "е" идет мантиса, степень, в которое возводится целое число до "е", для получения дробно/десятичной части
правильно?

Comment: То есть нужно получить два целых числа, а потом их перевести в битовой вид?

Comment: Вам нужно посмотреть материалы о форматах вещественных в процессоре. 1) Это зависит от архитектуры процессора. 2) Вам надо узнать как машинное представление сопоставляется с байтами в C#, которые вы можете увидеть в своей программе (по адресу вещественной переменной).

Comment: Две части числа с мантисой, это и есть формат числа с плавающей запятой для архитектуры х86.

Comment: вывод вот такой (01000000010000001001001101110100) впринцепи он так и выглядет 1бит - знак, следующие 8бит - это экспонента, и последнии 23бита- это мантиса вот это число мне нужно получить. это число - 3.009;

Comment: Вот в математике я не силен, могу только расписать формальные  требования к алгоритму.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование целой части вещественного числа и вывод строки

```
public static string  ToBinInt(double dec)
    {
        string str = "";
        while (dec > 0)
        {
            str =String.Concat(Convert.ToString(dec%2),str);
            dec = Math.Truncate(dec/2);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Преобразование дробной части вещественного числа и вывод строки
len - число знаков после запятой числа, в двоичной системе счисления

```
public static string ToBinFrac(double frac,int len)
    {
        string str = "";
        int c;
        int n = 0;
        while (n < len)
        {

            frac *= 2;
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(frac));
            str = String.Concat(str, Convert.ToString(c));
            frac -= c;
            n++;
        }
        return str;
    }
```