# Перевод из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную с запятой

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, помогите с кодом к такой программке, необходимо чтобы она могла переводить из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную с запятой. Сейчас имеется:

```
     if (comboBox1.Text == "10")
        {
            int d = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
            string[] hexArray = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
            if (hexArray.Length == 2)
            {
                string tmp = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexArray[0]), d) + ',' + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexArray[0]), d);
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(tmp);
            }
            else
            {
                string result = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), d);
                textBox2.Text = result;
                label5.Text = "321";
            }
        }
```

Но она переводит дробную часть в двоичную обычным методом, а не путем умножения дробной на основание новой

Answer (score 1):

[Преобразование вещественного числа в двоичное (10010) и наоборот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29840/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-10010-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)

Преобразование целой части вещественного числа и вывод строки

```
public static string  ToBinInt(double dec)
    {
        string str = "";
        while (dec > 0)
        {
            str =String.Concat(Convert.ToString(dec%2),str);
            dec = Math.Truncate(dec/2);
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Преобразование дробной части вещественного числа и вывод строки
len - число знаков после запятой числа, в двоичной системе счисления

```
public static string ToBinFrac(double frac,int len)
    {
        string str = "";
        int c;
        int n = 0;
        while (n < len)
        {

            frac *= 2;
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(frac));
            str = String.Concat(str, Convert.ToString(c));
            frac -= c;
            n++;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread697124.html

Перевод дробной части числа из десятичной системы счисления в любую другую систему счисления

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Входная строка
        string text;
        text1 = Console.ReadLine();
        //Преобразование в double 
        double text1;
        text1 = Convert.ToDouble(text);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", text1);
        //целая часть
        string zel;
        zel = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(text1)), 2);
        int zel1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(text1));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", zel, zel1);
        //дробная часть
        double text2;
        text2 = text1 - Math.Truncate(text1);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", text2);

        //цикл
        int cc;
        Console.WriteLine("Система счисления");
        cc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] asd = new double[10];
        asd[0] = text2;

        string drob = null;

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            switch (cc)
            {
                case 2:
                    asd[i] = (2 * asd[i - 1]) - Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 2);
                    int bin = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 2));
                    Console.WriteLine("bin={0}", bin);
                    drob += bin;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    asd[i] = (8 * asd[i - 1]) - Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 8);
                    double oct = Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 8);
                    Console.WriteLine("oct={0}", oct);
                    drob += oct;
                    break;
                case 16:
                    asd[i] = (16 * asd[i - 1]) - Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 16);
                    string hex;
                    hex = Convert.ToString(Math.Truncate(asd[i - 1] * 16));

                    int ze;
                    ze = Convert.ToInt32(hex);

                    switch (ze)
                    {
                        case 10:
                            hex = "A";
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            hex = "B";
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            hex = "C";
                            break;
                        case 13:
                            hex = "D";
                            break;
                        case 14:
                            hex = "E";
                            break;
                        case 15:
                            hex = "F";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("hex={0}", hex);
                    drob += hex;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", zel, drob);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```